# Kendo grid column menu extension

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, kendo-grid, column-chooser

Kendo grid provides an option to choose columns when we set "columnMenu: true"

I need to save the chosen columns in database. How to achieve the same in Kendo Grid?

[image]